# Can a Unix socket ever die if the server and client have no issue?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, unix-socket

Assuming I have a perfect server and a perfect client, both running on the same machine.

The server opens an `AF_UNIX` socket and listens on it.

The client connects to that socket.

They start communicating...

Can that `AF_UNIX` socket ever go bad? (assuming the client and server are both perfect, in other words, they have 0 bugs)

I'm asking about opposed to a TCP connection between two remote computers, which can go bad at any moment if any of the connections between those two computers goes bad at any point.

Obviously, I understand the either the client or the server can decide to exit and that will kill the communication.

Comment: Are you asking if there's anything currently that would cause the connection to fail, or are you asking if there is a guarantee being made by the AF_UNIX API that under no circumstances could a connection ever fail?  (I can easily imagine it being the case that e.g. in the current version of your OS, an AF_UNIX connection won't ever fail, but that the developers of the OS reserve the right to cause to it fail in the future under some circumstances, in which case you'll want to implement the appropriate error-handling anyway, just so your program won't break after the user upgrades his OS)

Comment: Not counting bugs in the OS, I don't believe so.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner It would be more like compared to a TCP connection which can be dropped along the way rather than a really bad failure like OOM or Disk I/O lock up (because you have an NFS—but who uses that now?!)...

Comment: This is wild speculation, but imagine a security-oriented OS that allows the user to specify whether processes can communicate with each other or not.  The user runs his client and server program and they start communicating, and then the user goes into his security panel and disables inter-process communication, at which point the AF_UNIX connection is cut off to enforce the new security policy.  (Would that ever happen?  I don't know.  Could it happen?  Sure, why not?)